# javascript - hide / show div based on selection

Tags: javascript

I have a rails form where user has to select a value from a drop down menu and based on that value, the rest fo the form elements are displayed.

```
<div id="A">
a
b
c
</div>

<div id="B">
x
y
z
c
</div>

<div id="B">
w
a
q
c
</div>
```

When user selects value A from the select menu, the div with id A is displayed and the rest of the divs are hidden.

The problem is some fields are repeated in the different divs and when user enters a value for field 'a' in div A, this value gets overwritten by the blank value in div B, although div B is hidden from view.

I would like to know whether it's possible to have the same fields in different divs and be able to store the value of the field found in the displayed div only, even if that field is found in other divs.

Many many thanks for any suggestion provided.

Comment: Need to see the HTML really.  Are you using the same `name` attributes for the inputs in each div? That'll be the problem.

Comment: I agree with Nick Brunt. And whether div is hidden or not is **not important**, only the names are important. In addition, two elements having same id is not good...

Comment: yes i agree with both of u. The thing is that based on the selection made in the selection list, the respective div containing the input field is displayed. Now when user enters a value in that input field, an ajax call is made and data retrieved from the dbase is displayed on the form. The way the data is displayed is different for each selection made in the select list

Comment: Just a thought - it's bad practice to use the same `id` for more than one element. Though it's probably possible to write code around it, that's generally not accepted as good practice by the community. Most people use classes instead if they have to use the same one twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hide your div, turn on the disabled attribute for all children and when you show a div remove it.  Something like this:

```
var showDiv = function ( id ) {
    var all = [document.getElementById( 'A' ), 
               document.getElementById( 'B' ), 
               document.getElementById( 'C' )],
        cur = document.getElementById( id ),
        inps;

    for (var i = 0, il = all.length; i < il; i++) {

        inps = all[i].getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var j = 0, jl = inps.length; j < jl; j++) {
            inps[j].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
        }

        all[i].style.display = 'none';

    }

    inps = cur.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (j = 0, jl = inps.length; j < jl; j++) {
        inps[j].removeAttribute('disabled');
    }

    cur.style.display = 'block';
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the suggestions provided :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not give the fields slightly different values, and check which one is actually filled out with an onsubmit function.

You have:

a1
b
c1



x
y
z
c2



w
a1
q
c2

Then in onsubmit:
if(a1 !='') { submit a1}
else if(a2 != '') {submit a2}

Sorry, not exactly code, but it's a place for you to start from.