# HTML&JS If Selected my values, open textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I want selected `3` value in the `select` form, opening `textarea` instantly. I do not want the page to be refreshed.

```html
<select id="work">
  <option value="1" selected="">Waiting</option>
  <option value="2">Accept</option>
  <option value="3">Failed</option>
  <option value="4">Transfer</option>
  <option value="5">Finish</option>
</select>

<textarea id="notes"></textarea>
```

Comment: Default text area is hidden and you want to show it if the select box selected value is 3, correct?

Comment: Yes. Problem is solved

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript - hide / show div based on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024207/javascript-hide-show-div-based-on-selection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the `textarea` using CSS
In a function check to see if value 3 is selected
and then making it visible

HTML:

```
<select id="work">
  <option value="1" selected="">Beklemede</option>
  <option value="2">İş Alındı</option>
  <option value="3">İş Alınamadı</option>
  <option value="4">Atölyede</option>
  <option value="5">Teslim Edildi</option>
</select>

<textarea id="notes"></textarea>
```

CSS:

```
#notes {
  display: none;
}

#notes.show {
  display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
const source = document.querySelector("#work");
const target = document.querySelector("#notes");

const displayWhenSelected = (source, value, target) => {
    const selectedIndex = source.selectedIndex;
    const isSelected = source[selectedIndex].value === value;
    target.classList[isSelected
        ? "add"
        : "remove"
    ]("show");
};
source.addEventListener("change", (evt) =>
    displayWhenSelected(source, "3", target)
);
```

Comment: Nice... It caused minor design bug, but that's okay. Thanks spacemonki.
I'm using "flex" instead of "block" for design bug.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Set you HTML:

```
 <Select id="work">
        <option value="1" selected="">Beklemede</option>
        <option value="2">İş Alındı</option>
        <option value="3" >İş Alınamadı</option>
        <option value="4">Atölyede</option>
        <option value="5">Teslim Edildi</option>
</Select>

<div id="3" class="textholder" style="display:none">
<textarea id="notes"></textarea>
</div>
```

Your javascript:

```
$(function() {
        $('#work').change(function(){
            $('textholder').hide();
            $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
        });
    });
```

Here is the JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pixelmedia/8bzvyLsr/2/

Comment: Thanks but  if again another option selected, must none textarea.

Comment: You didn't include this with your original post, but you can expand on the function above to hide. Generally on stack overflow, you don't follow up with another question.

Comment: Yes, that's my fault. My English is not good. Thank you for your helped.